# Content overlapping in constraint layout - Jetpack Compose Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have two icon buttons and a text element that I need to position within a constraint layout using Jetpack Compose. I want one button on the left, one on the right, and the text centered between them. However, my current implementation results in text overlapping with the buttons when the text content dynamically changes. How to resolve this issue.

**My implementation**

[image]

**Expected UI**

[image]

Here is the my implementation

```
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
) {
    val (
        backButton, titleText, favoriteButton,
    ) = createRefs()

    RoundIconButton(Modifier.constrainAs(backButton) {
        start.linkTo(parent.start)
        top.linkTo(parent.top)
        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
    }, icon = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack)
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(titleText) {
            start.linkTo(backButton.end)
            end.linkTo(favoriteButton.start)
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
        },
        text = "TestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestData",
        style = TextStyle(
            fontSize = dpToSp(dp = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.font_normal)),
            fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.poppins_regular)),
        )
    )
    RoundIconButton(
        Modifier.constrainAs(favoriteButton) {
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
        },
        icon = Icons.Filled.Favorite
    )
}
```

Comment: Try to se the width of the titleText like this :  width = Dimension.fillToConstraints, inside the constrainScope of the titleText, under the line bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing below things

1. `end.linkTo(titleText.start)` in backButton
2. width = Dimension.fillToConstraints for titleText which will fill required width

**Code**

```
ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        val (
            backButton, titleText, favoriteButton,
        ) = createRefs()

        RoundIconButton(Modifier.constrainAs(backButton) {
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            end.linkTo(titleText.start)
            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
        }, icon = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack)
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(titleText) {
                start.linkTo(backButton.end)
                end.linkTo(favoriteButton.start)
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
            },
            text = "TestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestDataTestData",
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = dpToSp(dp = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.font_normal)),
                fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.poppins_regular)),
            )
        )
        RoundIconButton(
            Modifier.constrainAs(favoriteButton) {
                start.linkTo(titleText.end)
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            },
            icon = Icons.Filled.Favorite
        )
    }
```